# Dans quelque temps

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

If you say

> Dans **quelque temps** je vais prendre un avion pour Paris

does that mean that the plane will take off **soon/in a short while** or does it rather mean that the upcoming event will take place s**ome time in the near future** (but in a longer while than *soon*)?

Comment: Second option, I wouldn't expect it to be soon...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is definitely **some time in the near future**. Although it is not strictly defined, when hearing "dans quelque temps" I would imagine anything between a few weeks and a few quarters, depending on the context. But it would not be a few days or shorter.